# Why didn't the query return any rows?

Tags: db2

Why didn't the query return any rows?

```
SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 WHERE 1 NOT IN (2, NULL)
```

Comment: `1 NOT IN (2, NULL)` == `1 <> 2 AND 1 <> NULL`. `1 <> NULL == UNKNOWN`. So, the result of the expression is: `TRUE AND UNKNOWN` which is `UNKNOWN`. But you get the result for rows, where an expression in WHERE evaluates as `TRUE` only.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I think your comment should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`1 NOT IN (2, NULL)` is equal to `1 <> 2 AND 1 <> NULL`
The result of `1 <> NULL` is `UNKNOWN`, so, the result of the original expression is:
`TRUE AND UNKNOWN` which is `UNKNOWN`.
But you get the result for rows, where an expression in WHERE evaluates as `TRUE` only.